# Understanding wireless channel model as a component of the whole communication system pipeline. What am I missing in the process?

Tags: channel

Disclaimer: I am not an expert in communication and signal processing. For simplicity of the discussion, I only consider scalar values.

Consider a communication system where a sender transmit a message signal $x \in \mathbb C$ on a channel with gain $h \in \mathbb C$, and then a receiver gets the signal $y \in \mathbb C$ from the sender according to the following channel model

$$ y = hx + n,$$
where $n \in \mathbb C$ is channel noise. I understand that $x$ is obtained through modulation in physical layer.

In most signal processing literature that I have read, they do not assume anything about the transmitted message other than a fact that it is complex-valued. At first, it is make sense because in the physical level, message is transmitted through an EM wave that inherently has amplitude and phase components, which somewhat related to complex numbers.

However, my confusion arises when I delve into the equation deeper. I assume that the message $m$ that I want to transmit is a scalar real value (i.e. $m \in \mathbb R$). So, $m$ is converted to $x$ through (edit: analog) modulation. I also assume the absence of source and channel coding so there is no need to discuss digital communication for a certain use case. When the receiver has a perfect CSI, it can recover the transmitted signal as
$$\tilde x = h^{-1} y =  x + h^{-1}n.$$
How do I recover $m$ from $\tilde x$? My issue is since $\tilde x$ is a complex value, it is definitely not a good estimate for $m$ given that $n$ and $h$ are random variables. The receiver knows that the message is real-valued. I suspect demodulation is the answer but I am not sure how it can be done. I have taken communication courses but they assume single-tone message signals etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For simplicity of the discussion, I only consider scalar values.

So you're only describing *flat* channels, otherwise you couldn't do that!

> In most signal processing literature that I have read, they do not assume anything about the transmitted message other than a fact that it is complex-valued. At first, it is make sense because in the physical level, message is transmitted through an EM wave that inherently has amplitude and phase components, which somewhat related to complex numbers.

Correct. The space of signals we can transmit on a carrier is "any complex-valued function of time as long as it's sufficiently band-limited".

> that I want to transmit is a scalar real value (i.e. m∈R).

A complex value **is** a scalar! This probably explains a bit of your confusion. The field that we're doing this math on is the complex numbers, so all scalars we deal with are complex numbers.

> How do I recover $m$ from $\tilde x$? My issue is since $\tilde x$ is a complex value, it is definitely not a good estimate for $m$ given that $n$ and $h$ are random variables.

Welcome to communications engineering, where everything you take is always noisy!

Yes, if you have perfect CSI, just divide by the channel (unless it's zero, in which case, just go and play cards instead, you're not receiving anything).

For your flat channel, where $h$ is just a complex scalar value, that's fine – the noise gain is exactly your SNR.

For the non-flat channel case, things get more hairy, and a channel is not always invertible, for all frequencies. You will want to look into things like *zero-forcing equalization* (so called because it literally divides by the channel, forcing the channel to be a flat 0dB line) and MMSE.

Generally, what you're very precisely describing is that recovering the transmitted signal from a noise observation is an *estimation problem*, and what you're hinting is that for different signals and different goals, the optimization problem of "what is the best decision I can make, given this $x$" varies.

The book that you'd be recommended here is Steven Kay's *Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing, Volume I: Estimation Theory*, but it's hard to acquire these days. If you want to dig right into channel descriptions and detection, estimation and channel uncertainty, Tse and Viswanath give away their book *Fundamentals of Wireless Communications* [for free](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Edntse/wireless_book.html). I like it, though it pretty much requires you to have either an extremely quick understanding, or an idea of concepts like coherent reception, PSK/QAM/FSK to begin with. 
Should you want a slower, but slightly more mathematically systematic introduction, Amos Lapidoth offers his *A foundation in digital communications* textbook [for free](https://www.afidc.ethz.ch/A_Foundation_in_Digital_Communication/Home.html) as well! It will take you on a longer ride, but it might really be *the* book for you if you're into detection theory and come from a communications background.

Comment: "A complex value **is** a scalar!"  Errrr, I think you meant to say that a **scalar** is also a complex number (in which the imaginary part is zero)

Comment: @DilipSarwate no. A complex number is a scalar. The complex numbers are the field over which we do our maths (especially, from which we build our vectors), and the elements of a field are called scalars. Simple test: the result of a scalar product is a scalar, and we know that the scalar product of two signals tends to be a complex number :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask if the received signal ($y$) is complex, is the estimation happens before or after demodulation? I guess demodulation maps the complex signal into real signal.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what happens. If you have perfect CSI, and you divide out the channel, then the imaginary part of the result is purely contributed by noise. That's easy to see if you write down the channel division operation in amplitude/phase: $$\frac{1}{h}= \frac{1}{\lvert h\rvert \, e^{j\angle h}}=\frac{1}{\lvert h\rvert}\,e^{-j\angle h} ,$$ i.e., the division "rotates back" the phase shift that the channel did.

Comment: I disagree with your explanation _in light of OP's question_ which clearly suggests that the OP considers _scalar real value_ to mean a real number (cf. $m \in \mathbb R$).

Comment: @DilipSarwate object all you want, but the channel they specify is $h\in \mathbb C$, so the output of the channel is complex not real.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see your point. So if I remove the imaginary part of $\tilde x$, the estimate of x is guaranteed to be good in the sense of minimum error (e.g. MMSE)?

Comment: not specifically in the MMSE sense, but in the maximum likelihood sense, optimal in uncorrelated circularly symmetric noise (you're especially dealing with that if someone says "AWGN")! You're erasing half of the noise power, none of the signal power, and by arguments of symmetry of the probability density functions, this is the best you can do for your decision :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you mean the pdf of $\tilde x$? If it is the case, how do I know if it is symmetric for the case of say $h \sim \mathcal C \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $n\sim \mathcal C \mathcal N(0,1) $ ? But so far you have cleared my doubts.

Comment: when you say you have CSI, then $h$ is not circularly normally distributed, but determinstic! Without knowledge of $h$ at all, you don't know the phase of your channel, and hence, no information could be extracted at all.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I recover $m$ from $\tilde x$?

To supplement Marcus' answer: there is a mapping from messages $m$ to symbols $x$. For example, using 4-ASK (to keep all symbols real), you may have a mapping such as:

| message $m$ | symbol $x$ |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | -3 |
| 01 | -1 |
| 11 | +1 |
| 10 | +3 |

At the receiver, the mapping is from received (noisy) symbol back to message. Such a mapping involves probabilities: given the received symbol (the evidence), which symbol was most likely transmitted (hypothesis)? There are [a few different ways to calculate these probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoding_methods), the simplest of which is maximum likelihood decoding.

Comment: If the symbol is continuous would it be possible to decode in similar way (as per my original question)? I want to design a communication system with a single task that is transmitting parameters (real valued) and not using digital communication schemes (quantization, digital modulation, codebooks etc.).

Comment: @Interception Letting $x$ take __any__ real value is possible, but then removing noise becomes impossible. In my 4-ASK example above, if the received value is, say, 2.8, we know that the most likely transmitted symbol is 3 which corresponds to bits '10'. If 2.8 (and 2.81, 2.801,....) are possible, this becomes impossible. If I'm misinterpreting your question, please let me know.

Comment: Yes I agree that recovering $x$ is impossible if errors are not permissible. In the system, I forget to say that error is allowed with respect to a certain measure (e.g. MMSE). The problem now is if I use common estimation methods like MMSE, how can I get the estimated $x$ as a real number rather than a complex number due to noise and channel.

Comment: You simply make a decision that returns a real number. For ML decoding, that would be simply finding the real number that is closest to the received (complex) number.